# Nexus 2 - plugin development - events

Tags: java, nexus

Edit: i think i figured out that i have to use EventBus. Therefor i have to register my listener class (the one with @subscribe method) to the EventBus. How do i get the instance of Nexus' EventBus to register my "listener"?

i'm currently developing a webhook plugin for Nexus 2, more specifically OSS 2.13.0-01. Something like [this](https://github.com/vbehar/nexus-webhook-plugin) (for Nexus 1.x). The *eventinspector* though does not work like that in Nexus 2.x. I browsed the source code of Nexus 2.x [here](https://github.com/sonatype/nexus-public/tree/nexus-2.x), but i did not get the clue, yet. My idea initially was that i just have to implement a Listener and that's it, but i'm not able to get any event, nor do i see any good debugging opportunities to find out how. So: How can i listen to events to call my methods on occurrence of that event in nexus 2.x? Is the eventbus the way to go?

Thanks!
bigcrash

Comment: Do you need to use Nexus Repository 2? Webhooks are built in on Nexus Repository 3, if that is of use to you.

Comment: well, yeah i have to use Nexus Repository 2....but thanks, this adds to the number of arguments pro nexus 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure *what* events you are interested in, but I built a plugin that detects whether new artifacts are added to Nexus. I implemented a class

```
@Named
@Singleton
public class ArtifactFinder extends ComponentSupport implements EventSubscriber
```

and implemented a method

```
@Subscribe
public void onDeployEvent(RepositoryItemEventStoreCreate event)
{
  StorageItem item = event.getItem();
  writeOut(item, "+ "); 
}
```

Comment: Thanks, i really appreciate that! I will try and report back:)

Comment: this did not work, i updated my answer, maybe i am doing something wrong. The only thing i can say is that the plugin appears in the plugin list and is marked active :)

Comment: As you can see i updated the answer with a finally working class, 100% your solution. This solution was at first not working, because i initially used requestbin for testing and requestbin's cloudflare protection blocked my java apache-http "browser" signature.

Comment: Please restore your question and post the answer as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on JF Meiers answer, here is the working Version for Nexus Repository Manager OSS 2.13.0-01 where we want to get all ItemEventStoreCreate Events to send a webhook on storing an item:

```
@Named
@Singleton
public class testEventPlugin extends ComponentSupport implements EventSubscriber {

    @Subscribe
    public void onDeployEvent(RepositoryItemEventStoreCreate event) {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        GetMethod method = new GetMethod("http://api.webhookinbox.com/i/EfwQnwLM/in/");
        try {
            int statusCode = client.executeMethod(method);
            byte[] responseBody = method.getResponseBody();
            System.out.println(new String(responseBody));
        } catch (Exception e) {
            System.err.println("Fatal error: " + e.getMessage());
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            method.releaseConnection();
        }
    }
}
```

Thanks!
bigcrash